# Do I need to attribute an SO answer when I post an answer's code in a question

Tags: support

I just came across [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45966822/can-this-jquery-function-be-re-written-in-vanilla-js) that was very bad in the beginning as it was more or less a "give me the code" request. The question received two answers, one of which is

```
var input = document.querySelector('input');
input.onkeyup = function(){
    var showClass = 'show';
    var label = input.previousElementSibling;
    if(this.value !== '')
    {
      label.classList.add(showClass);
    }
    else
    {
      label.classList.remove(showClass);
    }
}
```

The other answer said literally "yes it's possible, but we won't write the code for you".

After that, it took a few minutes for the OP to edit their question:

> But I'm missing something. Only the first label in the form works. So
>   far I've got:

```
var input = document.querySelector("input");
input.onkeyup = function(){
    var showClass = "show";
    var label = document.querySelector("label");
    if(this.value !== '')
    {
      label.classList.add(showClass);
    }
    else
    {
      label.classList.remove(showClass);
    }
}
```

I've left a comment, and got below response

[image]

Apart from that this is, IMHO outrageous, how is it with SO's license? I know that you need to attribute a post you've taken from here, but how is it if you steal code from here and post it here again, saying it's your code?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> I know that you need to attribute a post you've taken from here...

That's correct.

We have very clear and strict [referencing requirements](https://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing), imposed by this site's [cc by-sa 3.0 license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/).

> ...but how is it if you steal code from here and post it here again, saying it's your code?

That is not allowed. Again, the referencing requirements are very clear about this.

It doesn't matter whether you're writing a question or an answer—**if you use or adapt someone else's work in any way, then you need to provide attribution**. It is really that simple.

Obviously we cannot govern what someone chooses to do in their own project or other places off the site. Mind you, it's still a clear violation of the license. It's just that moderators aren't equipped to police it. *On* the site, we take this very seriously and enforce it whenever we see it or in response to flags. Please let a moderator know whenever you see plagiarism.

The policy really is zero-tolerance when it comes to violations. It is not your job to go behind people and edit in the attribution that they omitted. If you want to leave a friendly reminder in a comment, that's your prerogative, but when it became obvious that was not going to be sufficient motivation, you should have escalated it.

I just handled a case where someone had code in their question, stolen from an answer elsewhere on this site, without proper attribution. I thought that's what this Meta question was about, but no, this was an entirely different case. It happens more often than we wish. :-(

Comment: Thanks. Do I still need to flag the post or can you handle it without an additional flag?

Comment: @baao I'll get it. Thanks.